# Get an exception when acquiring mutex after a service restart

Tags: c#, mutex

I'm writing a windows service with c#. It reads continuously from a MSMQ by calling `Read()` from a thread :

```
public string Read()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!readMutex.WaitOne(100))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var message = queue.Receive();
            return (string)message.Body;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Exception:" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            readMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The mutex is created in the class constructor and disposed in the destructor.

The problem is that, after I stop and restart the service, I always get a `AbandonedMutexException` at the `if (!readMutex.WaitOne(100))` the first time `Read()` is called.

After attaching a debugger and adding breakpoints, I found that when the service is stopped, the `finally` block is never entered, I'm not sure if that would be the problem.

It's maybe not a big problem because the next time `Read()` is called, the exception   is no longer raised. But I'm wondering is there's a simple way to solve this?

**Append 1** :
I found that destructor is always called when the service is stopped, so I tried release mutex in the destructor. But found that I'm not allowed to release it ,because the mutex seems to be acquired in a different thread context.

**Append 2**:
For those who are interested in this question, I'll add what I've found after examining what's going on.

I tested that if I create a program which acquires a mutex without releasing it, and then close the program, the next time the program run, it can still acquire the mutex successfully without any exception. This is contradictory to this problem's symptom, and also contradictory to what I used to think.

I think the truth is that the OS close the mutex for me when the program quits, so next time I can acquire it.

But why I failed with this service? Finally I found that I had another second service which also created this path's mutex. That second service just kept a mutex handle, without doing anything to it(e.g. waiting on it ). In this case, when my first service restart and try acquire the Mutex again, it gets the exception.

In conclusion, when the program terminates with an unreleased mutex:
1) if the mutex is also referenced by any other services/applications, then next time the mutex is acquired, an exception will be raised.
2) if it's the only program referencing this mutex, then the os will handle this gracefully for me, and no error will be reported at next acquisition.

Comment: Is this an XY problem?  What is the `Mutex` for?

Comment: Have you considered reading MSMQ asynchronously?

Comment: @MickyD sorry I don't quite understand what an XY problem is. I use `Mutex` here to avoid multiple readers reading the queue simultaneously.

Comment: @MickyD This read is called by many parts of the project, so I'd like not to modify its mechanism, say changing it to event based... Also, I read that `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` are not thread safe.

Comment: I actually agree, im not sure why the mutex is there, just use a lock?

Comment: @MickyD after some reading, I got what an XY problem is. The problem I want to solve is just to not get the Exception after a service restart, other descriptions are just for information purpose. But if there's not a simple way based on current implementation, I'll just give up because it doesn't have much impact on my program.

Comment: If all the readers are in the same process, use a `lock` (which is kinda like a Windows critical section).  They more light weight but more importantly, wont lead to the problems you are encountering.  Your understanding of what is and isn't thread safe is in error

Comment: @MickyD I see, so what I'm doing is wrong, I shouldn't use a mutex here so there'll be no problem, I think I'll close this question. But there're situations where multiple writers in different process trying to write into the queue, which I think I'll need a `Mutex`, right? (maybe I should have another question for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readMutex.ReleaseMutex();` is most likely never being called when the service shuts down

More so, `Receive` blocks until it receives a message, so its likely that when the service is shutting down it times out, thinks that is has hang, and kills the process without closing gracefully.

There are several approaches here,

You are probably better to call `MessageQueue.Receive Method (TimeSpan)` with a **short** timeout, and adjust your logic accordingly, this way (on shut down) the  receive will hopefully timeout before the service timesout.

The other approach is running this in a thread or task and killing it on the shutdown and make sure you call `readMutex.ReleaseMutex()`

Anyway you have enough information now, and you should be able to solve this in a way that suits you

Comment: For the first approach: I fount that the service stops without any timeout, so I assume the system doesn't wait for `receive()` to timeout, but just kill it maybe. so there's still chances the service is stopped during this span. I think it's not a robust sollution..

Comment: For the second, could you please be so kind to give more information about where to implement the release?  And currently the message read part is a seperate module the other services reference, and changing the mechanism means a lot work.So I'm really expecting a simpler way if there is one..

Comment: @mosakashaka without seeing how you have built this its hard to give any more advice. however i think you are aware of the problem now, `readMutex.ReleaseMutex();` needs to be called one way or another.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the problem is because `readMutex.ReleaseMutex()` is never called. And currently I run out of ideas how to make `readMutex.ReleaseMutex()`  is always called on a service stop...

Comment: @mosakashaka log it and prove it to your self

Comment: @mosakashaka TheGeneral is giving you fine advice but you seem reluctant to even try

Comment: @MickyD I've added my comment above. Approach one is not robust enough because there's still chances in the timespan. Approach two, I don't know how, e.g., where can I release this mutex when a finally block is not reached...

Comment: Anyway, I think I'll just accept this answer, because there's no way to solve this in my current implementation. Maybe I have to re-write this part. Thank you!